# Setting List at the bottom of the screen in JS

Tags: javascript, web, mobile, web-frontend, mobile-devices

I have a bunch of posts and each one has a setting btn and a setting list, so in mobile version, I want to show the setting list from the bottom of the screen wherever the user is rightnow like Youtube, Facebook & Quora.

```
<button>Click Me 1</button>
<div class="setting">
  <ul>
    <li>Save</li>
    <li>Edit</li>
    <li>Delete</li>
    <li>Report</li>
    <li>Close</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
          settingLists = document.querySelectorAll('.setting');

    for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      const btn = btns[i];
      const settingList = settingLists[i];

      btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        settingList.style.position = 'absolute';
        settingList.style.display = 'block';
        const settingListTop = btn.getBoundingClientRect().top + btn.getBoundingClientRect().height + btn.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - settingList.getBoundingClientRect().height ;
        console.log(`${settingListTop}`);
        settingList.style.top = `${settingListTop}`; /*******/
        settingList.style.width = '99%';
      })
    }
</script>
```

the js code above really makes sense, I am getting the bounding dimensions using **getBoundingClientRect()** and it gives me some right results in the console, but it doesn't assign this variable value to the top of the setting div element in this line of code

> settingList.style.top = `${settingListTop}`;
> [image]

So how can I assign a variable value to the bottom of an element **OR** is there another way to make this task in JS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use window.matchMedia() option to check for viewport width and then apply the styles accordingly from js.
Why not just edit css styles from js?

Comment: the problem is we don't know where the bottom of the screen really is! so I tried to calculate it in order to set it to the setting list element..

Comment: Did you mean if element is in viewport or not?

Comment: If you're logic is correct all you need is to add "px" at the end of your settingListTop

Comment: yes is it in the viewport or not how to check for that?

Comment: settingList.style.top = `${settingListTop}px`. It won't work unless you add "px".

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: the logic doesn't work, I reckon it is harder than that

Comment: if I'm right you're trying to set a menu from top to bottom of the screen.. you can use `position fixed top=0, bottom=0` for that